# HashSet contains substring

Tags: java

I have a HashSet of Strings in the format: `something_something_name="value"`

```
Set<String> name= new HashSet<String>();
```

Farther down in my code I want to check if a String `"name"` is included in the HashSet.  In this little example, if I'm checking to see if `"name"` is a substring of any of the values in the HashSet, I'd like it to return true.

I know that `.contains()` won't work since that works using `.equals()`.  Any suggestions on the best way to handle this would be great.

Comment: you will have to loop over the set and call substring of each element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your existing data structure, the only way is to iterate over all entries checking each one in turn.

If that's not good enough, you'll need a different data structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep another map where name is the key and something_something_name is the value.
Thus, you would be able to move from name -> something_something_name -> value. If you want a single interface, you can write a wrapper class around these two maps, exposing the functionality you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a map (name -> strings) as follows:

```
 Map<String, List<String>> name_2_keys = new HashMap<>();
 for (String name : names) {
     String[] parts = key.split("_");
     List<String> keys = name_2_keys.get(parts[2]);

     if (keys == null) {
         keys = new ArrayList<>();
     }
     keys.add(name);
     name_2_keys.put(parts[2], keys);
 }
```

Then retrieve all the strings containing the name `name`:

```
 List<String> keys = name_2_keys.get(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted a `MapFilter` class [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13531687/823393) a while ago.

You could use it like:

```
MapFilter<String> something = new MapFilter<String>(yourMap, "something_");
MapFilter<String> something_something = new MapFilter<String>(something, "something_");
```

You will need to make your container into a `Map` first.

This would only be worthwhile doing if you look for the substrings many times.