# Get a sublist of a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

Lets say I have a `hashmap` with key `String` and value is also a `String`. I want to extract for a certain `key` element range a sublist(like with the `sublist` function of `List`) of the `values` of the map.

How could that be realized?

Comment: What are the semantics of this element range?

Comment: For a `HashMap`, there can be only one value for a key.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis the values of the HashMap are the same as in another list.

Comment: @rgettman OP might mean all the values that map to the range of keys?

Comment: @C.B. yes that is correct!

Comment: You'd need to iterate over the list of keys, and lookup each key individually.

Comment: A hashmap doesn't provide a way to get values for a range of keys. You need to get all the keys, identify which are in the desired range, and pull out the corresponding values. That's really the only way to do it. A Tree-based map would be better suited for this. Eg. `Treemap.subMap(...).values()`.

Comment: Are you expecting the output to be a `List` of values or a `Map` of key/value?

Comment: @crush It just should be a list of values

Comment: All `SortedMap` have a `subMap` method, you should look into this.

Comment: What does the data for the key element look like (e.g. "A12", "Z123B")? What would a "range" look like?

Comment: Are you looking for a [MapFilter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13531687/823393)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty naive example.

Let's say you have a `HashMap` that looks like the following:

```
public Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

You're saying that you want to create a sublist, so I'll assume you want a `List<String>` as an output:

```
public List<String> getKeyRange(Integer start, Integer end) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
        String value = map.get(i); //Forgot that string can be null in Java

        if (value != null)
            list.add(value);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As I said in comments, I wouldn't go for an `HashMap`, but for a `SortedMap` instead (a `TreeMap` per example), which have a `subMap` method :

```
subMap(K fromKey, K toKey)
```

> Returns a view of the portion of this map whose keys range from
>   fromKey, inclusive, to toKey, exclusive.

---

```
SortedMap<String, String> m = new TreeMap<>();
m.put("aaa","1");
m.put("bbb","2");
m.put("ccc","3");
m.put("ddd","4");
m.put("eee","5");

SortedMap<String, String> subM = m.subMap("a","d");
System.out.println(subM);
```

Output :

```
{aaa=1, bbb=2, ccc=3}
```

If you need only the list of the values, use the `values()` method.

Answer (score -1):

```
<K, V> List<V> getAll(Map<K, V> map, Collection<K> keys)
{
    List<V> values = new ArrayList<V>(keys.size());
    for(K key : keys)
    {
        values.add(map.get(key));
    }
    return values;
}
```

Comment: I think you misread the question. And you can directly call `map.values()` to get all the values in the map. Not the downvoter by the way.

Comment: He doesn't want all the values though, only some. If OP can define his "range" as a collection, this will do what he needs.