# Semi-Unique Nested Java Map?

Tags: java, dictionary, nested

I've seen a few questions about this, but not one that actually pertains to what I am trying to do.

Example of what I need:

I have a key(String), key(String), value(Integer):

"Salt", "Salt", 0

"Salt", "Pepper", 1

I want to be able to call:

```
map.get("Salt"), and have it:
  A: Return "Salt" and "Pepper"
map.get("Salt").get("Salt")) and have it:
  A. Return 0
map.get("Salt").get("Pepper")) and have it:
  A. Return 1
```

I've tried nested Linked/hashmaps, but adding the second salt value overrides the first...and I can't figure out how to have it so the second key does not override the first one.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I'd say a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>` would make it easier to satisfy the first example.

Comment: If you are prepared to encode your keys into a single string (e.g. "Salt.Salt" and "Salt.Pepper" then you could use a [MapFilter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13531687/823393).

Comment: @AndyTurner
The issue with this is that when I add: ("Salt", "Pepper", 1), ("Salt", "Salt", 0) gets overridden, so that's why I cant use that.

Comment: @user2684552 I guess because you might simply be using `put`. Use `map.computeIfAbsent("Salt", k -> new HashMap<>()).put("Pepper", 1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`:

```
Map<String, Map<String. Integer>> map =
    new HashMap<>();
```

Add values like this:

```
map.computeIfAbsent("Salt", k -> new HashMap<>())
    .put("Salt", 0);
map.computeIfAbsent("Salt", k -> new HashMap<>())
    .put("Pepper", 1);
```

Then, for your examples:

1. `map.getOrDefault("Salt", emptyMap()).keySet())`
2. `map.getOrDefault("Salt", emptyMap()).get("Salt")`
3. `map.getOrDefault("Salt", emptyMap()).get("Pepper")`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with following class. See the [working code here](https://ideone.com/WczPMQ):

```
class CustomMap<K1, K2, V>
{
    private HashMap<K1, HashMap<K2, V>> map;
    public CustomMap()
    {
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void put(K1 key1, K2 key2, V value) {
        HashMap<K2, V> lMap = map.get(key1);
        if(lMap != null) lMap.put(key2, value);
        else
        {
            lMap = new HashMap<>();
            lMap.put(key2, value);
            map.put(key1, lMap);
        }

    }

    public Set<K2> get(K1 key) {
        HashMap<K2, V> lMap =  map.get(key);
        return lMap == null ? null : lMap.keySet();
    }

    public V get(K1 key, K2 key2) {
        HashMap<K2, V> lMap =  map.get(key);
        if(lMap == null) return null ;
        return lMap.get(key2);
    }
}
```

Following is sample code for use:

```
    CustomMap<String, String, Integer> map = new CustomMap<>();
    map.put("Salt", "Salt", 0);
    map.put("Salt", "Pepper", 1);

    System.out.println(map.get("Salt"));
    System.out.println(map.get("Salt", "Pepper"));
```

**Output**:

```
[Salt, Pepper]
1
```